# Interpretation of Fredholm Alternative with respect to PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, compact-operators

I have studied the Fredholm Alternative, which states the following:

Theorem:
Let $K:H \rightarrow H$ be a compact linear operator and let $I$ be the identity operator on $H$. Then:

1.$N(I-K)$ is finite dimensional.

2.$R(I-K)$ is closed.

3.$R(I-K) = N(I-K^{*})^{\perp}$

4.$N(I-K) = \{0\}$  <=> $R(I-K) = H$

How does the theorem imply the following with respect to partial differential equations:

$(\alpha) = \{\text{for each }f\in H, \text{ the equation $u - Ku = f$ has a unique solution.}\}$

or else

$(\beta) = \{\text{The homogenous equation } u - Ku = 0 \text{ has solutions }u \neq 0 \}$

Thanks

Comment: This is not only true for partial differential equations, this is true for any equation which satisfies the hypothesis of theorem.

Comment: Okay but can you see how it follows from points 1 -4?

Comment: You alread has a answer by @gerw

Comment: Okay so he showed $(\alpha)$ <=> $\neg(\beta)$. The only point used directly was point 4. then?

Comment: Yes, we only need 4. But in order to prove 4, one typically uses 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes thanks I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha$ implies that $I - K$ is bijective, hence injective, giving in turn "not $\beta$".

Not $\beta$ says that $I - K$ is injective, hence you get the bijectivity from 4. This gives $\alpha$.